# React Native crashing on iOS with react-navigation drawer

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

I'm getting an error on iOS only:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._callListeners.bind')

This error is located at:
  in DrawerLayout (at DrawerView.js:161)
  ...
```

Project dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.2.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "7.2.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "5.0.0",
    "expo": "31.0.2",
    "expo-cli": "2.5.0",
    "native-base": "2.8.1",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.57.8",
    "react-redux": "6.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "3.0.8",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "6.1.0",
    "redux": "4.0.1"
  }
```

This started when I began using react-navigation; but works fine on Android.

Here's the code where we're using react-navigation, this is the main app the imports include the Home and Settings screens:

```
//imports...

const routes = {
  Home: Home,
  Settings: Settings
};

const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(routes);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {}

  render() {
    if (this.state.isReady) {
      return (
        <AppContainer/>
      );
      }
      else {
        return (<Container><Spinner/></Container>);
      }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this._loadAssets();
  }

  async _loadAssets() {
    await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
      Roboto: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf"),
      Roboto_medium: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf")
    });

    this.setState({ isReady: true });
  }
}
```

Comment: Use version 2. Version 3 is still buggy.

Comment: Did it work before? it is a new project or did you update dependencies?

Comment: doesn't look like you have `react-native-gesture-handler` installed, did you follow this guide: https://reactnavigation.org/blog/2018/11/17/react-navigation-3.0.html

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak it's using Expo - which according to those instructions negates the need for react-native-gesture-handler.

Comment: @HelmerBarcos It was working on iOS prior to adding react-navigation.

Comment: have you just added react-navigation, or did you upgrade from 2.0 to 3.0 recently? can you show the code where you're using react-navigation?

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak Just added react-navigation and I've updated the question with the code where we're using it.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the issue is `react-navigation` try setting your dependencies to match what expo expacts for sdk 31: https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v31-0-0-is-now-available-cad6d0463f49 and then clear your metro cache and delete and reinstall node_modules

Comment: I think it's something with RN - though I can't figure out what it is.  I've tried setting up exactly as Expo requires - and get the same error.

Comment: could you set-up a minimum [demo in snack](https://snack.expo.io/) so that we could reproduce it

Comment: Unfortunately @TarekBaz I'm unable to reproduce it in a snack - but when exporting the code from a snack I get the same problem locally...?

Comment: @Patrick I have exact same issue. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @NrN Not yet, but I'm glad I'm no longer suffering alone!  From the best I can tell it might be something to do with a .babelrc file that I'm using. I'm trying to define some additional aliases.  Do you have a .babelrc file in your root directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get this to work after a lot of iterating through possible solutions.

It looks like I had a few issues - with package version conflicts and .babelrc configuration.

With these I was able to get up and running..

package.json deps:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.2.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/core": "3.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "3.1.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "5.0.0",
    "expo": "31.0.6",
    "native-base": "2.10.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "6.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "3.0.9",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "1.0.5",
    "react-redux": "6.0.0",
    "redux": "4.0.1"
  }
```

And .babelrc in my root dir:

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./"],
      "alias": {
        "_framework": "./framework",
        "_apps": "./apps"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this same error by making the following change to my `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  "plugins": [
-    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "decoratorsBeforeExport": true }]
+    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }]
  ]
}
```

My `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "mobx": "^5.8.0",
    "mobx-react": "^5.4.3",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.57.8",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.24.3",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.0.0-beta5",
    "react-native-haptic-feedback": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^8.0.10",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.0.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9",
    "rollbar-react-native": "^0.4.0"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^13.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.5.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

besides adding the babel plugin I also had to run

```
expo start --clear
```

to make it work